# Por que o meu código não imprime?

Tags: c

Gostaria de saber porque que esse código que estou criando não imprime nada quando eu o compilo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (void)

{
    int dadoacerto, vidadrizzt, vidaartemis, dadod, dadoa, CAd = 8, CAa = 5, dadoataqdr, dadoataart;

    scanf("%d\n%d\n%d", &dadoacerto, &vidadrizzt, &vidaartemis);

    srand( (unsigned)time(NULL) );

    dadod = rand() % dadoacerto;
    dadoa = rand() % dadoacerto;

    if(dadod>dadoa)
    {
        dadoataqdr = rand() % 8;//Drizzt ataca primeiro

        if( dadoataqdr>CAa)
        {
            vidaartemis = vidaartemis - dadoataqdr;
            printf("Drizzt %d", dadoataqdr);        
        }
    }   
    else if(dadoa>dadod)
    {
        dadoataart = rand() % 5 + rand() % 5;

        if(dadoataart>CAd)
        {
            vidadrizzt = vidadrizzt - dadoataart;
            printf("Artemis %d", dadoataart);
        }
    }
    else if (dadoa==dadod)
    {
        dadoataqdr = rand() % 8;//Drizzt ataca primeiro

    if( dadoataqdr>CAa)
        {
            vidaartemis = vidaartemis - dadoataqdr;
            printf("Drizzt %d", dadoataqdr);        
        }
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Quando compila ou quando executa? Provavelmente não está entrando em nenhum `if`. Coloque um `else` para testar

Comment: A primeiro coisa que o programa faz é o `scanf()`. Certifica-te que introduzes 3 valores para o programa nao ficar parado nessa instrucao.

Comment: Quando clico em "compilar & executar" no DEV C++, não imprime nenhum valor, só a opção para a entrada dos valores de scanf

Comment: Sim, o scanf() esta correto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu programa esta com alguns erros de logica. Eu executei ele aqui e encontrei, acho, o principal problema pelo qual o seu programa não esta imprimindo uma saída. Esta ocorrendo o seguinte, quando o seu programa entra em um if, por exemplo o primeiro, ele vai ter que testar ainda para entra no if interno caso a condição seja falsa o codigo com o printf não será executado  e o programa não vai poder executar nem um outro comando dentro de um else, assim, ele não vai imprimir nada no final. Como eu não entendi muito bem qual a finalidade desse programa fica um pouco dificil arrumar, mas você so precisa tomar um pouco mas de cuidado com a lógica do if-esle.

Uma possivel sugestão seria você combinar as duas condições em um if só usando o operador &&.

Comment: Mas caso a primeira condição não seja satisfeita o programa não deveria testar o else if posterior?? ou seja, o primeiro if, o segundo e terceiro else if??

Comment: Sim, mas o que esta acontecendo é que o seu programa esta entrando, por exemplo, no primeiro if, mas não esta entrando no if dentro deste. Para você pode ver melhor a situação inclua um comando de printf dentro do primeiro if ai você entenderá o que esta acontecendo. E também com ele ja entrou em um if ele não vai entrar em nem um outro esle. E se ele não entrar no primeiro if e entra em um else-if depois pode acabar ocorrendo a mesma coisa do caso do primeiro.